# Compilation errors after import of "cumulocity-agents" project of Cumulocity in STS

Tags: maven, compilation, project, cumulocity

I downloaded the "cumulocity-agents" project of Cumulocity from Bitbucket, then imported it as "Existing Maven projects" in STS and i get a lot of compilation errors.

I changed the settings.xml of Maven as described in the Bitbucket page of the project, installed Lombok, but still had a lot of errors. Then I started fixing the errors as providing information to STS from which jars to load some classes. This errors were almost fixed, but I still have errors in the pom.xml files.

The erros at the top of the pom files are the following:
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java:clients-java:8.18.12: Failure to find com.nsn.cumulocity.root:root:pom:8.18.1 in http://resources.cumulocity.com/maven/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of cumulocity-maven-repo has elapsed or updates are forced

Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java:microservice-dependencies:pom:1005.1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://
     resources.cumulocity.com/maven/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of cumulocity-maven-repo has elapsed or 
     updates are forced

And then there are different other errors in the pom files.

Please advise how to fix this or tell me what I am doing wrong when trying to compile the project locally.

Answer (score 0):

cumulocity-agents Is not a public repository and its content is not desiged to be used, compiled or developed on by external people.

Please refer to the internal documentation for details on how to work with the project.